# Safe plugin API for ruby application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, api, plugins

What is the recommended approach building a plugin API for a ruby (rails) application?

How can i prevent developers monkey patching over core types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't prevent developers from monkey-patching your code (or *any* code, for that matter). This is Ruby!

Why would you want to do that anyway?

Comment: Haha yep and it's part of the reason I love ruby.. Just wondered if it was theoretically possible :P